# using mpdf convert webpage to pdf file but style css not support(codeigniter php)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

webpage to pdf convert using mpdf in codeigniter is done but problem is that pdf support only their default font and style. they not convert my same webpage design to pdf.  please any one help for the same

Comment: As you may have realized PDF libraries such as mpdf, tcpdf supports basic css features. If you want to render complex HTML + CSS 3.0 to pdf you will have to go for [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)

Comment: can convert full html webpage(webpage design by bootstrap) and i want to convert full webpage with same design amd color , margin,padding + font style convert to pdf

Comment: As I said, wkhtmltopdf can convert Complex HTML to exact PDF with all the details you mentioned.

Comment: thank u for help but i got some other solution for mpdf

Comment: @DineshPithiya I have the same issue. It would be really grateful if you could include the solution you found as the answer of this question.

Answer (score 0):

http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=457

http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=254

Read both this url and get result.